# You must specify 'to' property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I am trying to use `Link` instead of anchor tag. In this `Link` tag i am using the `to` property but it gives me error, such as, "You must specify 'to' property".

code of Nav.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
const Navbar = () => {
return (
<nav className="nav-wrapper grey darken-3">
  <div className="container">
    <Link className="brand-logo">Sherlock Holmes</Link>
    <ul className="right">
      <li>
        <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
      </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
 );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Code of App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavBar from "./components/Nav";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";

class App2 extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App2;
```

It gives me error on App.jsx page at ReactDom.render that you must specify 'to' property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem

```
<Link className="brand-logo">Sherlock Holmes</Link>
```

doesn't have a `to` attribute

Solution

```
<Link to="/some_link" className="brand-logo">Sherlock Holmes</Link>
```

Comment: Good thing to note when switching from regular links to router-based links: check those `href`s and make sure they are `to`s ;)

Comment: @RobertDundon Yeah! Its confusing at first, but we get used to it as we keep developing. Not sure why can't language/framework developer keep development experience consistent tho :X